# Trying to convert object to integer to show as a percentage, but it only shows 0

Tags: c#

I have an `object` value in data type `decimal(18,2)`.
I try to convert it to `integer` but data for value will show all 0 although actually 6.

I want to show value 0.06 as 6. Can anyone help me why it still shows 0?

```
<td class="line_table_td" style="text-align: center;">
  <%#GetPercentage(Eval("value"))%>&nbsp;
</td>

public decimal GetPercentage(object value)
{
    var perc = Convert.ToInt32(value);
    return(perc);
}
```

Comment: "i want to show value 0.06 to 6" that is not possible my frind. If you want to follow dirty way convert it to string and trim zeroes and decimal point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it should be a decimal value, then converting to an integer will drop the fractional portion.

Convert to a decimal first, then multiply it by 100 to get the "percentage" representation.

```
public decimal GetPercentage(object value)
{
    var percentage = Convert.ToDecimal(value) * 100;

    return percentage;
}
```

Comment: If decimal cannot direct convert it to integer but can multiply by 100. But, when multiply it with 100, value show 6.00. You know how to show only 6?  Cannot convert to Int?

Comment: wow its work. you are very good in converter. now result show 6. thank you very much Mr Grant Winney.